# Function like Cases/Select which also returns complement

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm looking for a function similar to `Cases` or `Select`, but that also returns the complement of the resulting list.

In other words, given some pattern, I want to split a list into two pieces:  one piece whose elements match the pattern, and another piece whose elements do not match the pattern.  I'd also be interested in a corresponding function that works with `Select`-style input rather than `Cases`-style input.

It's obvious how to do this in two function calls, but I only want to run through the list once.  (In the case of a long list, I don't want the combined operation to take the time.)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: user, I encourage everyone to wait 24 hours before Accepting an answer to let people around the world have a chance to respond.  In this case I think my answer is more complete than those provided before it and I hope you will consider it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I appreciate the advice, but I wouldn't consider your answer more complete without at least mentioning the built in function `GatherBy`.  That aside, the other points you brought up were helpful.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** If you have Version 10, you can use `GroupBy`:

```
Values@GroupBy[OddQ][Range[10]]
(* {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}} *)
```

`Values@GroupBy[Range[10],OddQ]` gives the same result.

---

Perhaps `GatherBy` with a boolean second argument, e.g.,

```
GatherBy[Range[10], OddQ]
(* {{1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your test can described as a binary pass/fail and it will only be applied at the first level of a `List` it is likely most efficient to use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) or [`GatherBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html).  `GroupBy` makes it easy to order the result e.g. always pass (true) first:

```
GroupBy[Range@20, PrimeQ] /@ {True, False}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, {1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20}}
> ```

If you are using an earlier version of *Mathematica* you will have to order the result of `GatherBy`:

```
SortBy[GatherBy[Range@20, PrimeQ], 1 - Boole @ PrimeQ @ First @ # &]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}, {1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20}}
> ```

However `Cases` does more than this:

- it works on arbitrary expressions
- it works with patterns
- it performs replacements
- it takes a *levelspec* and the [`Heads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Heads.html) option

The earlier answers did not address these points, therefore I shall, with:

```
separate[expr_, (L_ -> R_) | (L_ :> R_) | L_, arg___] :=
  Quiet @ Replace[L | _?(Sow@#; &) :> R, _[x_] :> x] //
    Reap[Cases[expr, #, arg], _, Sequence @@ #2 &] &
```

- The syntax is the same as `Cases` including *levelspec* and the `Heads` option, as these are passed directly to `Cases` itself.
- `_?(Sow@#; &)` serves as a fall-through when the given pattern does not match, therefore only non-matches are sown.

Examples:

```
separate[Range@10, x_?OddQ :> x/2]
```

> ```
> {{1/2, 3/2, 5/2, 7/2, 9/2}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}}
> ```

```
separate[
  {{foo, Pi}, -9.3, {False, 1.1}, 1, f[5, 7], True, 3/4},
  _[x_, _] :> x
]
```

> ```
> {{foo, False, 5, 3}, {-9.3, 1, True}}    (* 3 is split from Rational[3, 4] *)
> ```

```
separate[
  {{foo, Pi}, -9.3, {False, 1.1}, 1, f[5, 7], True, 3/4},
  _Symbol, {2}, Heads -> True
]
```

> ```
> {{List, foo, π, List, False, f}, {1.1, 5, 7}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way is to select the items you want and then take the complement of the set:

```
set = Select[Range[20], Mod[#, 3] == 1 &]; 
notSet = Complement[Range[20], set];
```

Speed-wise there is not much difference between this and GatherBy:

```
Timing[n = 1000000; full = Range[n]; 
 set = Select[full, Mod[#, 3] == 1 &]; 
 notSet = Complement[full, set];]
{0.803090, Null}

Timing[n = 1000000; full = Range[n]; 
 GatherBy[full, Mod[#, 3] == 1 &];]
{0.982641, Null}
```