# How to improve code speed for the large datasets?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning

How can I improve the speed of this code? It runs okay but is quite slow for large datasets, for example, 5 million elements.

```
ClearAll[filterData];
filterData[dataList_] := 
 Module[{totalEntries, removedEntries, remainingEntries, 
   determinantTest}, 
  determinantTest[{x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_, x5_, x6_, x7_, x8_, x9_, x10_, 
     x11_, x12_, x13_, x14_, x15_, x16_}] := 
   Return[Det[{{1, x1, x2, x5, x4, x8}, {x2, x1, x10, x3, x11, 
        0}, {x6, x1, x12, x14, x16, x15}, {x13, x2, x4, x6, x5, 
        x6}, {x2, x1, x3, x14, x10, x15}, {x13, x5, x8, x6, x2, 
        x6}}] == 0];
  totalEntries = Length[dataList];
  removedEntries = DeleteCases[dataList, _?determinantTest];
  remainingEntries = Complement[dataList, removedEntries];
  {totalEntries, removedEntries, remainingEntries}]

(*Example usage:*)
sampleData = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {5*10^6, 16}];
result = filterData[sampleData]
```

Comment: The `DeleteCases` / `Complement` thing seems unnecessary. Just use `Select[dataList, determinantTest]`. Or if you _really need_ the removed/remaining thing, then there's also `GroupBy[dataList, determinantTest]` which gets you an Association instead of a list.

Comment: @flinty, note that there is [not much speed difference](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73498/75628) between the two methods ... (`GatherBy` can actually be slower).

Comment: Also the example usage is maybe not representative of your real data. It's _almost certain_ that a random real 16x16 matrix has non-zero determinant. Maybe `RandomInteger` would be a better test case.

Answer (score 1):

For more performance on the CPU you may have to look into calling into an external library or using Mathematica's compilation tools.

But if you have *OpenCLLink* set up and a GPU installed, here's this abomination. It's very fast and could be faster (and a lot cleaner had I not unrolled the determinant). Runtime is about ~0.5 seconds on an NVIDIA 1080 Ti.

```
Needs["OpenCLLink`"];
source = "
__kernel void singular(__global mint* xs, __global mint* singular_mask)
{
int i = get_global_id(0);
int x1  = xs[i * 16 + 0];
int x2  = xs[i * 16 + 1];
int x3  = xs[i * 16 + 2];
int x4  = xs[i * 16 + 3];
int x5  = xs[i * 16 + 4];
int x6  = xs[i * 16 + 5];
int x7  = xs[i * 16 + 6];
int x8  = xs[i * 16 + 7];
int x9  = xs[i * 16 + 8];
int x10 = xs[i * 16 + 9];
int x11 = xs[i * 16 + 10];
int x12 = xs[i * 16 + 11];
int x13 = xs[i * 16 + 12];
int x14 = xs[i * 16 + 13];
int x15 = xs[i * 16 + 14];
int x16 = xs[i * 16 + 15];

int d = -(x11*x14*x4*x5*x6*x8)+x10*(x14*x16*x5*x6-x14*x4*x5*x6*x6+x14*
x5*x5*x6*x8+x10*x5*(-(x14*x6)+x5*x6*x6-x6*x6*x8))+x13*(x15*(x3*(-(x3*
x4*x5)+x11*x5*x5)+x10*(-(x10*x5*x5)+x16*x5*x5)+x2*((-x10+x16)*x2*x3+
x10*(x10*x5-x16*x5)+x3*(x3*x4+x10*x5-x11*x5-x16*x5)))+x10*(x10*x14*x5*
x8-x14*x16*x5*x8)+x3*(-(x11*x14*x5*x8)+x16*x3*x5*x8)+x2*(x10*(-(x10*
x14*x8)+x14*x16*x8)+x3*(x11*x14*x8-x16*x3*x8)))+x3*(x10*x4*x5*x6*x8+
x3*(-(x16*x5*x6)+x4*x5*x6*x6-x5*x5*x6*x8)+x5*(-(x11*x5*x6*x6)+x11*(
x14*x6+x6*x6*x8)))+x12*(-(x11*x14*x5*x6)+x10*x3*x5*x6+x15*(-(x3*x5*x5)
+x11*x5*x6+x2*(x5*x5*x5-x11*x6-x4*x5*x6+x2*(x3-x2*x5+x4*x6)))+x13*(
x15*(x3*x4*x5-x11*x5*x5+x2*(-(x3*x4)+x11*x5))+x11*x14*x5*x8-x10*x3*x5*
x8+x2*(-(x11*x14*x8)+x10*x3*x8))+x2*(x11*x14*x6+x14*x4*x5*x6+x3*(-(
x10*x6)-x4*x5*x6+x5*x5*x8)+x10*x5*(-(x5*x6)+x6*x8)+x5*(-(x11*x6*x8)+
x5*(x11*x6-x14*x8))+x2*(-(x14*x4*x6)+x3*x4*x6-x11*x5*x6+x11*x6*x8+x2*(
x14*x8-x3*x8)+x10*(x5*x6-x6*x8))))+x15*(x11*x4*x5*x5*x6+x3*(-(x10*x4*
x5)+x16*x4*x5+x3*x5*x5-x11*x5*x6-x4*x4*x5*x6)+x10*(x10*x5*x6-x16*x5*
x6-x5*x5*x5*x6+x4*x5*x6*x6)+x2*(-(x11*x4*x5*x5)-x16*x4*x5*x5+x10*(x5*
x5*x5-x10*x6+x16*x6+x4*(x5*(x5-x6)-x6*x6))+x11*x5*x6*(-x6-x8)+x2*(x11*
x6*x6+x2*(x2*x3+x3*(x5-x6)-x11*x6-x16*x6+x10*(-x5+x6))+x3*(-x3-x5*x5+
x4*(-x6-x8))+x11*x5*(x6+x8)+x16*x5*(x6+x8)+x10*(x4*x6-x5*x8))+x3*(x11*
x6+x5*x5*(-x5+x6)+x10*x8-x16*x8+x4*(x4*x5+x5*x6+x6*x8))))+x2*(x11*x14*
x5*x6*x6+x11*x14*x4*x5*x8+x14*x16*x4*x5*x8+x11*x14*x6*x8*x8+x3*(-(x14*
x4*x5*x6)+x3*(x16*x6-x4*x6*x6)+x5*(x11*x6*x6+x14*x5*x8)+x11*(-(x14*x6)
-x6*x6*x8)+x10*(-(x5*x6*x6)-x6*x8*x8)+x16*(-(x4*x5*x8)+x5*(x5*x6-x6*
x8)))+x10*(x4*(x14*x6*x6+x14*x5*(x6-x8))-x14*x5*x5*x8+x10*(x14*x6-x5*
x6*x6+x6*x6*x8)+x16*(-(x14*x6)+x5*(-(x5*x6)+x6*x8)))+x2*(-(x11*x14*x5*
x6)+x11*x14*(-x6*x6-x8*x8)+x16*(-(x14*x5*x6)-x14*x8*x8)+x2*(x11*x14*
x6+x14*x16*x6+x10*x14*(-x6+x8)+x3*(-(x16*x6)-x14*x8))+x10*(-(x14*x4*
x6)+x14*x5*x6+x16*(x5*x6-x6*x8)+x14*(-(x6*x8)+x8*x8))+x3*(x14*x4*x6+
x10*x6*x6+x3*x6*x8+x16*(x6*x8+x8*x8))))+x1*(x16*(x14*x4*x6-x14*x6*x8)+
x5*(x11*x6*x6*x8-x14*x6*x8*x8)+x11*(-(x14*x6*x6*x8)-x6*x6*x8*x8)+x10*(
x14*x6*x8+x6*x6*x8*x8+x5*(-(x14*x6*x6)+x5*x6*x6-2*x6*x6*x8)+x4*(-(x14*
x6)+x5*x6*x6-x6*x6*x8))+x4*(-(x14*x4*x6*x6)-x11*x5*x6*x6+x14*x6*x6*x8+
x11*(x14*x6*x6+x6*x6*x8))+x12*(-(x14*x5*x6)+x3*x5*x6+x2*(x14*x6+x14*
x5*x6+x2*(-(x14*x6)+x3*x6)+x3*(-x6-x5*x6))+x15*(x5*x6+x2*(-x6+x2*x6-
x5*x6))+x13*(x15*(x3*x5-x5*x5+x2*(-x3+x5))+x14*x5*x8-x3*x5*x8+x2*(-(
x14*x8)+x3*x8)))+x3*(x3*x5*(-1+x6)*x6+x16*(-(x4*x6)+x6*x8)+x4*(x4*x6*
x6-x6*x6*x8)+x10*(x4*(1-x6)*x6+x6*(-x8+x6*x8))+x5*(x14*x6-x5*x6*x6+x6*
(x6*x8+x8*x8)))+x13*(x2*x3*(x14*x8-x3*x8)+x10*(x14*x4*x8-x14*x8*x8)+
x16*(-(x14*x4*x8)+x14*x8*x8)+x3*(-(x14*x5*x8)+x3*x5*x8+x16*(x4*x8-x8*
x8)+x10*(-(x4*x8)+x8*x8))+x15*(x2*x3*(x3-x5)+x16*(x4*x5-x5*x8)+x10*(-(
x4*x5)+x5*x8)+x3*(-(x3*x5)+x5*x5+x10*(x4-x8)+x16*(-x4+x8))))+x15*(x3*
x5*x6*(-1-x8)+x5*x5*x6*x8+x11*x6*x6*x8+x10*(x4*x6+x5*x6*x6-x6*x8)+x16*
(-(x4*x6)+x6*x8)+x4*(-(x11*x6*x6)+x4*x6*x6-x6*x6*x8)+x2*(x2*(x4*x5+x3*
(-x4-x6)+x10*x6-x2*x6+x5*x6+x6*x6)-x11*x6*x8+x5*(-x6*x6-x5*x8)+x16*(
x4*x6-x6*x8)+x4*(x11*x6-x4*x6-x5*x6+x6*x8)+x10*(-(x4*x6)-x5*x6+x6*(-
x6+x8))+x3*(x6+x4*x6+x5*(x6+x8))))+x2*(x16*(-(x14*x4*x6)+x14*x6*x8)+
x11*(x14*x6*x8+x6*x8*x8)+x4*(x14*x4*x6+x11*x5*x6+x11*(-(x14*x6)-x6*x8)
)+x3*(-(x14*x6)-x4*x4*x6+x3*(1-x6)*x6-x6*x6*x8+x16*(x4*x6-x6*x8)+x5*(-
(x14*x6)+x5*x6-x6*x8-x8*x8))+x5*(-(x11*x6*x8)+x14*(x6*x6+x8*x8))+x2*(-
(x14*x5*x6)-x14*x6*x6+x2*(x14*x6-x3*x6)-x14*x4*x8+x10*(-(x14*x6)+x5*
x6-x6*x8)+x3*(x14*x6+x4*x8+x6*(x6+x8)))+x10*(x14*x6*(x6-x8)+x4*(x14*
x6-x5*x6+x6*x8)+x6*(x6*x8-x8*x8)+x5*(x14*x6-x5*x6+x6*(-x6+2*x8)))));

singular_mask[i] = d == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
";
singular = 
  OpenCLFunctionLoad[source, 
   "singular", {{_Integer, 1, "Input"}, {_Integer, 1, 
     "Output"}}, {16}];
data = RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, {5*10^6, 16}];
Timing[
 OCLresult = 
   First@singular[Flatten@data, ConstantArray[0, Length[data]], 
     Length@data];
 ]

singularvecs = Pick[data, OCLresult, 1];

reshape[x_] := {{1, x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[5]], x[[4]], x[[8]]}, {x[[2]], 
    x[[1]], x[[10]], x[[3]], x[[11]], 0}, {x[[6]], x[[1]], x[[12]], 
    x[[14]], x[[16]], x[[15]]}, {x[[13]], x[[2]], x[[4]], x[[6]], 
    x[[5]], x[[6]]}, {x[[2]], x[[1]], x[[3]], x[[14]], x[[10]], 
    x[[15]]}, {x[[13]], x[[5]], x[[8]], x[[6]], x[[2]], x[[6]]}};

(** Test Case **)
(** 
Timing[CPUresult=Boole[Det[reshape[#]]]==0&/@data;]
CPUresult==OCLresult
**)
```

Comment: `OCLresult` is a binary mask of the matrices that are singular (Det = 0), and `singularvecs` is the result of picking out the vectors using that mask that produce singular matrices. The giant expression is the determinant of your matrix (as you've written it in your question). This won't work for real valued matrices, just integers, but can be adapted by changing types.